# Why the tkinter function automatically repeats twice?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tk-toolkit, filedialog

When I try to build a simple UI, everything works well, except the tkinter function I used always repeats twice, I am not sure why this happens and how to deal with it. Here is an example code:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
dirname = tk.filedialog.askdirectory(parent=root, initialdir="/",title='Please select a directory')
print(dirname)
```

When I run this code, the function works well, it will let me select a folder, but after I select the folder, it asks me to select it again. And from the print(), it outputs both the folders I have selected.

What should I do to make it only run one time?

Comment: Are you importing this file? Is running this code in the REPL (e.g. IDLE) enough to properly replicate the issue?

Comment: Cannot reproduce the issue.  Note that `tk.filedialog.askdirectory(...)` cannot be executed.  You need to import the `filedialog` sub-module.

Comment: As written this code will not run since you didn't import tk.filedialog. Please provide an example that actually reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Hi can you try with below script, I tried running below script and it does not ask for second selection and dont print second selection as well;

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog as fd

root = tk.Tk()
dirname = fd.askdirectory(parent=root, initialdir="/",title='Please select a  
    directory')
print(dirname)
```

Comment: Well, it is the same, but I find if I create new project and only make the UI, the problem will not happen, so there may be a problem with the environment or other parts of the code, thanks.